# I need to create new column based on the condition of another column using pyspa

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe and I would like to add new columns based on conditions:

[image: Existing dataframe]

My desired dataframe should be created based on type and result columns

[image: result dataframe]

This is what I have tried but not able to achieve it

```
df1.select(
    col("*"),
    when(col("Type")=='Trucks1', col('new_col1'),
        when(col("Type")=='Trucks2', col('new_col1'),
            when(col("Type")=='Cars1', col('new_col2'))
        )
    )
)
```

What's the right approach to achieve this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are good examples here https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/

```
df1.select(
    col("Type"),
    when(df1.Type == 'Trucks1').
    when(df1.Type == 'Trucks2').
    otherwise("").alias("new_col1"),
    when(df1.Type == 'Cars1').
    otherwise("").alias("new_col2"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a `when` for each new column you want.

```py
df1.select(
    "Type",
    when(col("Type").isin("Trucks1", "Trucks2"), col("result")).alias("new_col1"),
    when(col("Type").isin("Cars1", "Cars2"), col("result")).alias("new_col2"),
)
```